# Computer randomly freezes one app at a time

Tags: windows-10, memory, ssd, freeze, gpu

**The problem**

My PC (Windows 10) randomly freezes a few times a day, first the app which is focused at the moment, then anything I try to interact with, from other apps to the Start Menu. During those freezes, I can't open any other app, not even the Task Manager (with Ctrl+Shift+Esc). It doesn't ever completely crash or reboot, I have to manually restart it with the power button every time (since the Start Menu is unresponsive). There is no apparent link to which apps are open at the time of freeze, I'm usually gaming but it has happened even with only Skype, Spotify, and Opera opened. Interestingly, I can continue Skype calls even during freezes.

**Background Story**

A few weeks ago I installed [Zorin](https://zorinos.com/) (Ubuntu) on Disk #1, with Windows 10 already installed on Disk #2 (Disk #0 is only used for storage such as portable apps, archives, backups, ...). I had lots of trouble installing graphic drivers, which I suppose is partly because I have a recent GPU, but managed to fix it by disabling safe boot, which from what I understood was blocking Zorin from using NVIDIA's graphic drivers. Everything was fine for a while, then one day I noticed that my log files were 60 GB each, so I rebooted just in case (*"Have you tried turning it off and on again?"*).
After that, I couldn't even enter Zorin anymore, there was just an unending list of errors; I tried lots of things but ultimately gave up and just wiped Disk #1 completely.

After that, I started having lots of blue screens on Windows, first because of a UNEXPECTED_STORE_ERROR exception, which I fixed, then because of a CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED exception, which I also managed to fix. I can't tell exactly what fixed them, because I don't remember exactly, but I can tell you some of the things I did:

- Disable Fast Boot;
- Enable Secure Boot;
- Reinstall Windows 10 completely on Disk #2;
- Properly install drivers with [Driver Easy](https://www.drivereasy.com/) (I had some devices which weren't even recognized by Windows at first);
- And probably some of the other things I'll mention for the current problem.

Finally blue-screen-free, I was able to use my PC normally, until the problem which I described started occurring a few times a day.

Below is a list of everything I remembered trying, nothing seemed out of the ordinary, no errors, normal benchmarks, ...

**What I already tried**

- Running `sfc /scannow`.
- Running DISM.
- Try to reinstall system drivers, delete some that I shouldn't have (I couldn't boot Windows anymore), then repair Windows with a bootable USB drive for Windows 10 (which if I'm not mistaken is close to a full reinstall). I tried running Driver Easy again, but all drivers were fine at that point.
- Unplugging then re-plugging all 3 SSD's, RAM, and GPU.
- Enabling/Disabling Fast/Secure Boot
- Resetting UEFI to default settings.
- Running Windows CHKDSK Tool on all 3 SSD's.
- Increasing virtual memory to 37 GB.
- Running Windows Memory Diagnostic.
- Running [Passmark PerformanceTest](https://www.passmark.com/products/performancetest/index.php) (results below).
- Running [FurMark](https://geeks3d.com/furmark/).

**Passmark PerformanceTest Results**

- PassMark Rating: 7219
- CPU Mark: 22846 (Expected 22752)
- 2D Graphics Mark: 926 (Expected 893)
- 3D Graphics Mark: 17756 (Expected 18105)
- Memory Mark: 2900
- Disk Mark: 25192 (Expected 22623? Not sure I got the right one)

**System Information**

```
OS Name:    Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
Version:    10.0.18363 Build 18363
Other OS Description:   Not Available
OS Manufacturer:    Microsoft Corporation
System Type:    x64-based PC
Processor:  AMD Ryzen 7 3700X 8-Core Processor, 4050 Mhz, 8 Core(s), 16 Logical Processor(s)
BIOS Version/Date:  American Megatrends Inc. 1820, 12/09/2019
SMBIOS Version: 3.1
Embedded Controller Version:    255.255
BIOS Mode:  UEFI
BaseBoard Manufacturer: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
BaseBoard Product:  PRIME B450-PLUS
BaseBoard Version:  Rev X.0x
Platform Role:  Desktop
Secure Boot State:  Off
PCR7 Configuration: Binding Not Possible
Boot Device:    \Device\HarddiskVolume2
Hardware Abstraction Layer: Version = "10.0.18362.752"
Installed Physical Memory (RAM):    32,0 GB
Total Physical Memory:  31,9 GB
Available Physical Memory:  23,1 GB
Total Virtual Memory:   36,9 GB
Available Virtual Memory:   25,5 GB
Page File Space:    5,00 GB
Page File:  C:\pagefile.sys
Kernel DMA Protection:  Off
Virtualization-based security:  Not enabled
Device Encryption Support:  Reasons for failed automatic device encryption: TPM is not usable, PCR7 binding is not supported, Hardware Security Test Interface failed and device is not Modern Standby, Un-allowed DMA capable bus/device(s) detected, TPM is not usable
Hyper-V - VM Monitor Mode Extensions:   Yes
Hyper-V - Second Level Address Translation Extensions:  Yes
Hyper-V - Virtualization Enabled in Firmware:   No
Hyper-V - Data Execution Protection:    Yes
```

**GPU Information**

Note: It says NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070 while it's actually an NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070 SUPER, not sure if that matters.

```
Name:   NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070
PNP Device ID:  PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_1F07&SUBSYS_21733842&REV_A1\4&1FC990D7&0&0019
Adapter Type:   GeForce RTX 2070, NVIDIA compatible
Adapter Description:    NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070
Adapter RAM:    (1.048.576) bytes
Installed Drivers:  C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_dispi.inf_amd64_e0a5a1b06de180e3\nvldumdx.dll,C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_dispi.inf_amd64_e0a5a1b06de180e3\nvldumdx.dll,C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_dispi.inf_amd64_e0a5a1b06de180e3\nvldumdx.dll,C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_dispi.inf_amd64_e0a5a1b06de180e3\nvldumdx.dll
Driver Version: 26.21.14.4575
INF File:   oem33.inf (Section001 section)
Color Planes:   Not Available
Color Table Entries:    4294967296
Resolution: 1920 x 1080 x 60 hertz
Bits/Pixel: 32
Memory Address: 0xF5000000-0xF5FFFFFF
Memory Address: 0xE0000000-0xEFFFFFFF
Memory Address: 0xF0000000-0xF1FFFFFF
I/O Port:   0x0000E000-0x0000E07F
IRQ Channel:    IRQ 54
Driver: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DRIVERSTORE\FILEREPOSITORY\NV_DISPI.INF_AMD64_E0A5A1B06DE180E3\NVLDDMKM.SYS (26.21.14.4575, 22,35 MB (23.439.288 bytes), 04/04/2020 15:00)
```

**Disks Information**

```
Description:    Disk drive
Manufacturer:   (Standard disk drives)
Model:  ADATA SU630
Bytes/Sector:   512
Media Loaded:   Yes
Media Type: Fixed hard disk
Partitions: 1
SCSI Bus:   1
SCSI Logical Unit:  0
SCSI Port:  0
SCSI Target ID: 0
Sectors/Track:  63
Size:   223,57 GB (240.054.796.800 bytes)
Total Cylinders:    29.185
Total Sectors:  468.857.025
Total Tracks:   7.442.175
Tracks/Cylinder:    255
Partition:  Disk #1, Partition #0
Partition Size: 223,57 GB (240.055.746.560 bytes)
Partition Starting Offset:  1.048.576 bytes

Description:    Disk drive
Manufacturer:   (Standard disk drives)
Model:  NVMe Samsung SSD 970 SCSI Disk Device
Bytes/Sector:   512
Media Loaded:   Yes
Media Type: Fixed hard disk
Partitions: 3
SCSI Bus:   0
SCSI Logical Unit:  0
SCSI Port:  3
SCSI Target ID: 0
Sectors/Track:  63
Size:   931,51 GB (1.000.202.273.280 bytes)
Total Cylinders:    121.601
Total Sectors:  1.953.520.065
Total Tracks:   31.008.255
Tracks/Cylinder:    255
Partition:  Disk #2, Partition #0
Partition Size: 529,00 MB (554.696.704 bytes)
Partition Starting Offset:  1.048.576 bytes
Partition:  Disk #2, Partition #1
Partition Size: 100,00 MB (104.857.600 bytes)
Partition Starting Offset:  555.745.280 bytes
Partition:  Disk #2, Partition #2
Partition Size: 930,88 GB (999.526.760.448 bytes)
Partition Starting Offset:  677.380.096 bytes

Description:    Disk drive
Manufacturer:   (Standard disk drives)
Model:  Samsung SSD 860 EVO 500GB
Bytes/Sector:   512
Media Loaded:   Yes
Media Type: Fixed hard disk
Partitions: 1
SCSI Bus:   0
SCSI Logical Unit:  0
SCSI Port:  0
SCSI Target ID: 0
Sectors/Track:  63
Size:   465,76 GB (500.105.249.280 bytes)
Total Cylinders:    60.801
Total Sectors:  976.768.065
Total Tracks:   15.504.255
Tracks/Cylinder:    255
Partition:  Disk #0, Partition #0
Partition Size: 465,75 GB (500.090.011.648 bytes)
Partition Starting Offset:  16.777.216 bytes
```

**Additional Information**

- I have a dual monitor setup, if that matters.
- I didn't build the PC myself, except for the Disk #2, and the GPU.
- My PSU is a [Corsair VS550](https://www.corsair.com/uk/en/Categories/Products/Power-Supply-Units/vs-series-config-2018/p/CP-9020171-UK)

Comment: Can you give us information about your power supply unit?

Comment: I thought that was in the System Information, I added it to Additional Information

Comment: I suppose the Window Event Viewers don't give much clue nor does analyzing any mini dump files, correct? I would suspect a buggy graphic driver issue based on your information. I'd dig thru event logs though around the freeze time and see if you see anything that points to anything being an issue, application exception, etc. I would suspect strongly graphics related since it freezes and no BSOD regardless of how long you wait, correct? Eliminate loose HDMI, or DVI or whatever cable you are using. I'd also unseat and reseat all RAM and GPUs. Bugging video driver perhaps for your system hardware

Comment: Good job with detail thoroughness too!! Great effort you've done, I hope someone can help you get this resolved here.

Comment: There are only some warnings in the System Event Viewer from DistributedCOM about permissions, and while I admit I had little patience to test how long it would last, it never ended crashing, BSOD or not.

Comment: I'm just trying to guess what could be the reason of your problem. A Windows system problem would have been solved by Windows 10 new installation. I doubt  that the problem could be caused by the Linux-based installation. The hardware configuration is updated and quite powerful, except for the PSU. The Corsair VS550 is an entry level model, whose [release](https://www.pc-specs.com/psu/Corsair/Corsair_VS550/1221) dates back to 2012. I don't know if this is the cause of your problems, but it could be

Comment: I tried reseating RAM and GPU yesterday in the morning and it didn't crash until today, not sure if it means it changed something or if it was just random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I noticed that if apps like Skype and some overlays still worked, while things like YouTube didn't. I thought about it for a while, and realized this probably meant that my RAM was fine, and that the problem most likely came from my SSD.

To verify this (and don't do this at home kids), I live-unplugged my SSD and was able to exactly recreate my problem. While doing that, I noticed that my SSD was actually loose, and after putting it back in and checking the screws twice, I haven't had the problem for a few weeks, so I supposed it's safe to say that was it.